# How to get a value from inside Anko's async? (KotlIn)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-activity, android-asynctask, anko

I have a function which uses [Anko's](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) async in order to call Google's Distance API and get the distance from one location to another. unfortunately i don't know how to get the data from inside the async and pass it to another function. the code looks something like this

```
fun getDistance(location1:LatLng,location2:LatLng){
    async{
        val result = URL(url).readtext() 
        uithread{
            //Parser
            //distance value
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to also mention im really new to kotlin or android development in general, please be kind.

Comment: Not quite sure what your question is, could you elaborate a little more? Also - why not do the `Parser` stuff async as well?

Comment: Thats just it, I parsed the returned data from google which is inside that uithread bracket and extracted the distance from the parsed data. Now what I want to do is to get the distance when the getDistance function is called. but when I try to put return distance it does not work.

Comment: If it would, your function wouldn't be async, as the function calling it would be waiting for the return. What do you want to do with the returned value?

Comment: Im using it to re arrange an ArrayList of LatLng based on the smallest distance from one place to another. Is there no other way to get the value?

Comment: Good news, Anko is deprecated.

Comment: aw, it is! Now I have to read EVEN MORE things!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to tackle this; pass an object to the function with your array in it that gets rearranged in your function, or go with something like:

```
fun getDistance(location1 : LatLng, location2 : LatLng, f: (Long) -> Unit){
    doAsync{ // Anko is deprecated as I have been made aware
        val result = URL(url).readtext()
        val distance : Long = // parse result
        uiThread{
            f(distance)
        }
    }
}
```

and call that with

```
getDistance(loc1, loc2) { toast("The found distance was $it") }
```

This is by no means the only way to go; you could update a larger-scoped variable, call a listener, put your lat-longs in a class with updating functions that are called, or a bunch of other ways that I am too lazy to think about :)